# How to put Fragment over ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using the `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` for navigation,

What I'm trying to do is have another fragment open (like a new screen) over the `ViewPager`

On my Activity i do:

```
FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
trans.add(R.id.main_layout, frag);
trans.addToBackStack(null);
trans.commit();
```

But i guess my problem is that the `ViewPager` isn't either a `Fragment` or in `R.id.main_layout`

This is the `activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!--
        This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page
        titles for adjacent pages.
    -->

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've also tried to `trans.add(R.id.pager, frag)` and it also doesn't work.

What happens is that the other fragment opens but the `ViewPager` is still below receiving input.

EDIT here's some more info:

My MainActivity is a Swipe Views + Title Strip. On one of the views i show a grid and when the user clicks on the element of that grid i want to show a new "view" (maybe not the right term).

For example I show albums in my grid and when the user clicks on the albums I'll show the photos on that album.

I think this is like starting a new activity, but I'm using a `FragmentActivity` and when i try to show a new `Fragment` i'm not able to replace the `FragmentActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use DialogFragment instead.
2. Do not use the parent RelativeLayout as the Fragment container, write a empty RelativeLayout above the ViewPager.
3. If the above methods do not work, hide the ViewPager when showing a new Fragment.

EDIT: layout sample

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you give an example of 2.? and is 1. a good way of doing it? Doesn't seem like its what dialogs should be used for.

Comment: DialogFragment use a new Window(Dialog) to show the Fragment. I think it's the right solution in your situation. The second is more simple, i write a demo for you, have a try.

Comment: I would like to use the second, and it doesn't work. the ViewPager is still visible, i'll try the 1st way.

Comment: Ok, the ViewPager will always be visible, you do not hide it. But if your new Fragment is opaque, the ViewPager is invisible to user. You can set a white background to the new Fragment.

Comment: Hello, i've tried the dialog way, and it doesn't seem to be what i want, since it behaves like a dialog, I'll add some more context to the question.

Comment: Yes, it will like a default dialog. But you can change the theme of dialog, use FragmentDialog.setStyle(style, theme) to set a normal theme to it, just like android.R.style.Theme_Black.